# revision control a file without putting it in a directory

Tags: git, version-control

Can one do (Git) revision control for a text file without having to put it in a directory?

Idea is:  given a file `somepath/file.txt`

```
$ git singlefile init file.txt
```

creates a directory `.file.txt.git` at the same path `somepath/`, and stores Git repository info in it.  Some mechanism would then associate data in `.file.txt.git` with the file `file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason why you couldn't just ignore the rest of the files in the directory?

```
$ cd somepath
$ git init
$ echo "*" > .gitignore
$ git add -f file.txt .gitignore
```

If you want to have the repository called something other than `.git`, you can manually specify it via the `GIT_DIR` environment variable:

```
$ GIT_DIR=.file.txt.git git init
$ echo "*" > .gitignore
$ GIT_DIR=.file.txt.git git add -f file.txt .gitignore
```

(and to save some time, you could just export GIT_DIR into your shell)

Comment: If I do this for `somepath/file1.txt` and `somepath/file2.txt` and generate two repos `somepath/.file1.txt.git` and `somepath/.file2.txt.git`, when i run `somepath $ git status`,  how to specify which repository i want to work with?

Comment: `GIT_DIR=somepath/.file1.txt.git git status`